# PyQt4: How to make Icon bigger than QPushButton? (Pixmap Buttons)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I am struggling on making a Pixmap button, since there was no other option (That i knew) i tried using QIcon.

The picture that i wanted as button, was not fully square, i wanted to only show the pixmap, but with it still having a button function (Signals connecting to slots, etc.).

When i tried to make the Icons size equal to button, Icon would go up and it wouldn't fit in at all, and button would show outside of icon.

---

So the Question is:

How can i make icon greater than a QPushButton? so only icon would show and it would still have icon functions.

If this is over Icon borders, then is it any other way making Pixmap buttons?

Comment: May be try QToolButton ?

Comment: I have never used it before, should i do something like this? `btn = QtGui.QToolButton("", self) QToolButton.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/something"))` ?

Comment: I think QToolButton uses icons too, @user1034749

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use css to achieve that with the `background-image` property like this and also set the border to 0

```
btn.setStyleSheet("background-image: url('image.jpg'); border: none;")
```

Comment: It gave me invalid syntax error, i think because it has Quotation marks inside Quotation marks.

Comment: Button is still bigger than image, If i minimize it, so will image.

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm beginner and pyqt and i'm not exactly sure how to set margin and padding of button. Only options i had on button where these: `btn.resize(100, 100)` and `btn.move(520, 300)`, I also don't use layouts (sizers). @danidee

Comment: sorry for being annoying, but now button wouldn't show at all @danidee

Comment: hmmm that's strange. Update your question and show me exactly how you're doing it

Comment: oooh...my bad see my edit....apparently you have to set the style of a widget once

Comment: did you delete the other `setSyleSheet` ?

Comment: I removed the second line that would remove borders, should i add it back?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109537/discussion-between-danidee-and-shellrox).

Answer (score 3):

I use PySide. Maybe the codes are similar

```
btn = QPushButton('')
btn.setIcon(QPixmap(image path))
# adjust width and height to fit the size of button.
btn.setIconSize(QSize(width, height))   
# set zero border.
btn.setStyleSheet('QPushButton{border: 0px solid;}')
```